# Why isn't my Linux VM connecting when the Host OS (M1 MacOS) uses a VPN?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vpn

Situation:

- network from MacOS (Host) working with/without VPN
- network from Linux (VM) working only without VPN

Details:

- Mac OS Sonoma 14.2 (Host)
- Apple M1 chip (ARM 64)
- Parallels Desktop
- Linux Debian as Guest OS (VM)
- NordVPN app installed in the Host OS
- The VM is configured in Parallels as having Shared Network (marked as recommended)

Why isn't my Linux VM connecting when the Host OS (M1 MacOS) uses a VPN?

Comment: The real question  is why it should do that. You are describing expect behaviour.´

Comment: Why isn't it connecting where? Through the VPN? Elsewhere? What exactly are you seeing?

Comment: So I have a HOST OS (MacOS) and 2 Guest OSes/VMs: 1. Docker Desktop, 2. Parallels Desktop (both VMs are Linux). NordVPN is only installed in the Host. The network works in all 3 (1 host, 2 guests) when VPN is off but works only in 2 out of 3 when VPN in Host is on (works in Host and in Docker, but does not work in Linux from Parallels). Machine is MBP M1 (ARM).